# Change the length of the inhale and exhale in a css breathing pacer

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I found a tutorial about creating a breath pacer using CSS:

The inhale and the exhale in the code are the same (4s). I want to control with the code the inhale, post-inhale hold, exhale, post exhale hold timing.

How can I do it?

Tutorial link - https://css-tricks.com/recreating-apple-watch-breathe-app-animation/
codepen - https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/zKMEPE

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

.watch-face {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  animation: pulse 4s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) alternate infinite;
}

.circle {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  animation: center 6s infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #61bea2;
}

.circle:nth-child(even) {
  background: #529ca0;
}

.circle:nth-child(1) {
  animation: circle-1 4s ease alternate infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(2) {
  animation: circle-2 4s ease alternate infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(3) {
  animation: circle-3 4s ease alternate infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(4) {
  animation: circle-4 4s ease alternate infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(5) {
  animation: circle-5 4s ease alternate infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(6) {
  animation: circle-6 4s ease alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.15) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-35px, -50px);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(35px, 50px);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-3 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-60px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-4 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(60px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-5 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-35px, 50px);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-6 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(35px, -50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="watch-face">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "I want to control with the code" - what code and how do you want to control it? (e.g. with user input setting each of those values independently?).

Comment: Hello, just by changing the code in CSS manually.

Comment: So have you tried that (you can see all of the 4s being used in the CSS, what happens if you change one of them for example?).

Comment: I want the inhale, exhale and hold be different

Comment: Yes, so have you tried altering some but not all of those 4s to see what happens?

Comment: It's not related. The 6 circles represent each different circle in the animation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Have you investigated the cubic-bezier function? It seems currently to be set at things being equal. This is a helpful article: https://css-tricks.com/advanced-css-animation-using-cubic-bezier/

Answer (score 4):

This can be controlled by changing the animation `pulse`. For example, now I reduced the inhalation and increased the delay before exhalation:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

.watch-face {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  animation: pulse 4s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) alternate infinite;
}

.circle {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  animation: center 6s infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #61bea2;
}

.circle:nth-child(even) {
  background: #529ca0;
}

.circle:nth-child(1) {
  animation: circle-1 4s ease alternate infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(2) {
  animation: circle-2 4s ease alternate infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(3) {
  animation: circle-3 4s ease alternate infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(4) {
  animation: circle-4 4s ease alternate infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(5) {
  animation: circle-5 4s ease alternate infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(6) {
  animation: circle-6 4s ease alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.15) rotate(180deg);
  }
  /*  */
  60% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  /* ☝️ */
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-35px, -50px);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(35px, 50px);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-3 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-60px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-4 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(60px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-5 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-35px, 50px);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-6 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(35px, -50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="watch-face">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the way to go. Firefox and Chrome have nice build in tools to adjust the `cubic-bezier` function and play around with it. Inspect the element with `animation` on it and click the littel icon next to it. The editor in firefox is a bit more complex than the chrome one.

Comment: How can I make the inhalation 40% and the exhalation 60% with no holds? thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I want to control with the code the inhale, post-inhale hold, exhale, post exhale hold timing.

The inhale, exhale are determined by the `animation` duration, is was `4s`, I've introduced an [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) to easy change that: `--duration`. For example change it to `8s` to double the duration.

---

> hold timing

The hold timing is not that easy, since there is no CSS property to 'hold' between an `ease alternate infinite` `animation`.

The easiest way to get your output is by adding a `keyframe` that does not apply any change, eg: it waits.

`100%` keyframe means it's back to the start, so if we copy/paste the `keyframe` and change the middel frame to `50%`, the animation won't do anything between `50` and `100` procent, so it's 'hangs'

Please play around with the values, I've set it to `75%` so it won't animate between the `75%` and `100%` duration (`--duration` long)

The same idea can be applied to the `0%` frame so it 'hangs' before the growing phase.

```css
:root {
  --duration: 4s
}

body {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

.watch-face {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  animation: pulse var(--duration) cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) alternate infinite;
}

.circle {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  animation: center 6s infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #61bea2;
}

.circle:nth-child(even) {
  background: #529ca0;
}

.circle:nth-child(1) {
  animation: circle-1 var(--duration) ease alternate infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(2) {
  animation: circle-2 var(--duration) ease alternate infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(3) {
  animation: circle-3 var(--duration) ease alternate infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(4) {
  animation: circle-4 var(--duration) ease alternate infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(5) {
  animation: circle-5 var(--duration) ease alternate infinite;
}

.circle:nth-child(6) {
  animation: circle-6 var(--duration) ease alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.15) rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(-35px, -50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-35px, -50px);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(35px, 50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(35px, 50px);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-3 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(-60px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-60px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-4 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(60px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(60px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-5 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(-35px, 50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-35px, 50px);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-6 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(35px, -50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(35px, -50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="watch-face">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I want the inhale and exhale length be different not the same

Comment: Ow that was not clear, but if you want to set a amount of second for the start you cant use `ease alternate infinite` but need to add multiple frames to have more control.

Comment: What do you mean by adding multiple frames? can you edit your answer please?

Answer (score 1):

I have added another animation percentage to overcome the alternate sequence. I hope this helps.

```css
:root{
  /*  you can set desired time as you want */
  --duration: 6s;
  --anim-circle: ease-out infinite;
} 

body {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

.watch-face {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  animation: pulse  var(--duration) cubic-bezier(0.65, 0.05, 0.36, 1) infinite;
}

.circle {
  height: 122px;
  width: 122px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.circle:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #61bea2;
}

.circle:nth-child(even) {
  background: #529ca0;
}

.circle:nth-child(1) {
  animation: circle-1 var(--duration) var(--anim-circle);
}

.circle:nth-child(2) {
  animation: circle-2 var(--duration) var(--anim-circle);
}

.circle:nth-child(3) {
  animation: circle-3 var(--duration) var(--anim-circle);
}

.circle:nth-child(4) {
  animation: circle-4 var(--duration) var(--anim-circle);
}

.circle:nth-child(5) {
  animation: circle-5 var(--duration) var(--anim-circle);
}

.circle:nth-child(6) {
  animation: circle-6 var(--duration) var(--anim-circle);
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: scale(.15) rotate(-135deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-1 {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  80%, 90% {
    transform: translate(-35px, -50px);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-2 {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  80%, 90%  {
    transform: translate(35px, 50px);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-3 {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  80%, 90%  {
    transform: translate(-60px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-4 {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  80%, 90%  {
    transform: translate(60px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-5 {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  80%, 90% {
    transform: translate(-35px, 50px);
  }
}

@keyframes circle-6 {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  80%, 90%  {
    transform: translate(35px, -50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="watch-face">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```